# map function is not creating any div inside myContent div when I am using innerHTML for myContent div ,No result is coming ,no error in console

Tags: javascript, html, dom

**index.html**
You can See here myContent classnamed div is there inside which I want to add div of api data from index.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
            <div class="container">
                <div class="myContent">
                    
                </div>
               
        </div>
    
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

**index.js**
Here you can see I have used map function to map through each data of storeData array, but it is not working, DOM shows nothing

```
var storeData=[]

const getData=()=>{
    axios.get("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets? 
    vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false").then(
        res=>{
            storeData.push(res.data)
            //console.log(storeData)
        }
    )
}
getData();

const myContent=document.querySelector(".myContent")



    myContent.innerHTML=storeData.map((elem)=> {
    return`
    <div class='card'>
                    <div class="card-content">
                    
                        <h3>${elem.name}</h3>
                        <h3>${elem.symbol}</h3>
                        <h3>${elem.current_price}</h3>
            
                    </div>
                </div>
   
  `
});
```

Comment: I'm thinking `getData()` is asynchronous, so when you are mapping `storeData`, it hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: Also, you are jamming an array into myContent.innerHTML, so at the least you will probably get unwanted commas.  Suggest `storeData.map(your map function).join("")`

Comment: Yes ,you are correct , I used two then() methods and it worked